# Would OllyDbg help recognizing the passed parameters between the caller and the calle?

Tags: ollydbg

The calling convention used in assembly differs depending to the compiler, so I need to know 
How ollydbg2.01 would help me to recognize the parameters passed from caller to the callee and the values returned back from the callee to the caller for a CALL instruction.
The assembly which I am working on is compiled by Microsoft visual C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ollydbg already shows the parameters passed to a functions in the CPU window. This of course works for standard functions such as `printf` , `CreateFileA` which Ollydbg knows about. For example see the image below. The parameters to `CreateWindowExA` are shown.

[image]

Now the return value of a function is *usually* kept in register `eax` in `x86`. So just note the value after the function returns. Of course in case of a hand-coded assembly the return value may be anywhere.

Comment: But in general case like CALL 0049E6D0, Dose OllyDbg help recognizing passed parameters and returned values between caller and callee parts of assembly?

Comment: @user3778418 In a general case `ollydbg` cannot guess the number & types of parameters passed to a function. You need some other program for that like `IDA` which have better analysis capabilities.